# What does ":" (colon) operator in a bash variable expansion: VAR=${TEMP:3}?

Tags: bash

What is the meaning of the following line in a variable in `bash`?

```
VAR=${TEMP:3}
```

Comment: @chaos Please do not edit the question to match your answer better ;-).

Comment: @Pilot6 I haven't changed the meaning. Or do I understand something wrong? I made it better to find (title) and more readable.. BTW `:`  has also other meanings, it's a bash builtin command, for example. I wanted to differ from that, because the question is *obviously* not about that. What the user means is the `:` operator inside a variable name. I'm sorry, I don't want to annoy somebody, but your rollback makes no sense and should be reversed, but I don't want an edit-war here. Furthermore it's bash and scripting specific so why remove those tags?

Comment: You removed `TEMP` and `VAR` variables and changed the question the way that other answers lost the meaning.

Comment: @Pilot6 In my answer I don't refer to a `VAR` variable. But, however, you're free to change that one thing back. I wanted to make the question more general, less specific. It was never meant to sabotage other answers.

Comment: @Pilot6 If you got it that way, I apollogize.

Comment: @SnakeDoc no, it's on-topic all right

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is [variable expansion](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html#EXPREPL1) and works like this (notice this is only `bash` and `ksh` specific and will not work in a POSIX shell):

```
$ x=1234567890
$ echo ${x:3}
4567890
$ echo ${x:7}
890
$ echo ${x:3:5}
45678
```

---

- `${var:pos}` means that the variable `var` is expanded, starting from offset `pos`.
- `${var:pos:len}` means that the variable `var` is expanded, starting from offset `pos` with length `len`.

Comment: Woks in `zsh` too

Comment: @kos It's not worth mentioning, because everything works in `zsh` =) I made a diet script in `zsh` and lost 10kg in 1 week.

Comment: `zsh` for sure makes you dumber at typing paths when you're not using it :)

Comment: @kos Hehe, It's a bit like jquery: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19492

Comment: Ha, I love how the only answer attempting to really answer the question got -2 because of "not enough jQuery"! :)

Comment: It's not necessarily relevant from an Ubuntu perspective, but this is a ksh93 feature and not in ksh88 (which is, I assume, why it's not in POSIX).

Answer (score 7):

in bash it cuts away the first 3 characters of a (string) variable:

```
$ VAR="hello world"
$ echo ${VAR:3}
lo world
```

have a look at 'substring extraction' here: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html .

Answer (score 2):

This operator cuts off the first 3 characters of variable `TEMP` and assigns the rest to variable `VAR`.